# Из каких компонент складывается время выполнения программы в настольной ОС?

Tags: время, ос

Из каких наименьших компонент складывается выполнение программы в настольной ОС (не real-time) в режиме x64?

Comment: Загрузка в память и запуск.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, не во всех настольных ОС это настолько незначительно.